# How to mark my current position on the osm map?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to do a simple thing. I would like to mark a point of my current location.
At the moment I have osm map that display the screen with my current location, on top of this I can see my current position (longitude and latitude), but I don't know how to mark the current location.

Comment: Dear Anna, please avoid crossposts as they consume a lot of energy of the community that likes to help everybody on solving problems.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81960/how-to-mark-my-current-position-on-the-osm-map

Answer (score 1):

I've not used OSMDroid a huge amount but you could mark your location using an `ItemizedIconOverlay`. This [sample](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/osmdroid/samples/SampleWithMinimapItemizedoverlay.java#64) should show you how to create the overlay, and then instead of creating an overlay list containing the cities, it instead should just have a single item which is your current location.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you are asking but you are probably looking for the `MyLocationNewOverlay`. This will monitor the GPS and plot an icon at your location. The [OpenStreetMapViewer](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/) sample covers this. The icon will move as your location moves so if you are looking to put a permanent marker that stays put then you want to use an `ItemizedIconOverlay`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the minimum amount of code to get a point to display. You need a "blue_pin" image in drawable and a layout with "mapview" component.

```
public static final GeoPoint berlinGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(52.516667, 13.383333);
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem("Berlin", "City", berlinGeoPoint);
Drawable markerDrawable= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_pin);
overlayItem.setMarker(markerDrawable);

ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemArrayList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
overlayItemArrayList.add(overlayItem);
ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> locationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(this, overlayItemArrayList, null);

MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapView.getOverlays().add(this.locationOverlay);
```